# How to move the sort and search buttons to the right in Antd Table header?

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am using Antd Table in my React application and I would like to move the sort and search buttons to the right side of the Table header. By default, these buttons appear on the left side of the header. I have tried to find a solution in the Antd documentation but couldn't find anything relevant.

How can I change the position of the sort and search buttons in the Antd Table header to the right side? Is there a built-in option to do this or do I need to override the default CSS styles? Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

I can update border radius and border with className and style but due to some reasons I can't update it in my codebase, the changes doesn't reflect. The ant-table class can't be overwritten neither with inline CSS nor with className. So I am looking forward to change it through ConfigProvider. How do I make it happen?

```
<Table
  columns={employeeColumns}
  dataSource={dataSource}
  loading={isLoading}
  rowKey={key}
  {...params}
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can simply use the `Space` component of `antd` or even a simple `<div>` to wrapp your buttons within it, then use `flex` and make `justifyContent: "end"` :

```html
<div>
  <Space
    style={{
      marginBottom: 16,
      display: "flex",
      justifyContent: "end",
    }}
  >
    <div>
      <Button onClick={setAgeSort}>Sort age</Button>
      <Button onClick={clearFilters}>Clear filters</Button>
      <Button onClick={clearAll}>Clear filters and sorters</Button>
    </div>
  </Space>
  <Table columns={columns} dataSource={data} onChange={handleChange} />
</div>;
```